# JS code to search exact occurrence of name in a text of characters

Tags: javascript, arrays

While going through the javascript basics on an [online tutorial](https://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript), I came across a problem, which searches for the occurrence of a person's name in a given set of characters (a string). The solution as discussed in the tutorial just copies n set of characters from the original string, beginning with a matching first letter, to an empty array. Here, n is the length of a person's name from the name array.

To modify the code such that the program copies only exact occurrences of a person's name into the empty array, I wrote this solution, but it has one flaw:

```
 var text = "Hey, how are you \
doing? My name is Manish. It's a really hot day in here. Nice to meet you \
Manish. Bye";
var myName = "Manish";

var hits = [];

for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if(text[i] === myName[0]) {

        for(var j = i, k = 0; j < myName.length+i, k < myName.length; j++,k++) {
                //if first letter is a match, check if next letter is a match
                if(!(text[j+1] === myName[k+1])) {
                    break;
                }
                else {

                    hits.push(text[j]);
                }
        }
    }

}
if(hits.length === 0) {
    console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
}
else {
    console.log(hits);
}
```

The last letter of the name is never printed (or pushed to the `hits` array). The output I get is:

```
["M", "a", "n", "i", "s", "M", "a", "n", "i", "s"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you only looking at the letters in front of you? Why is `myName[0]` a special case?

Comment: Btw, `j < myName.length+i,` (with the comma operator) is completely ignored. You probably want `j < myName.length+i &&`

Answer (score 2):

Because your inner loop compares the "next" character, and if that matches `push`es the current character. By the time you're "ready" to push the last matching character, you're comparing the next one, and that's not matching. `myName[k+1]` will actually be `undefined`.

Try like this: `if(!(text[j] === myName[k])) {`

Comment: If I use this `if(!(text[j] === myName[k]))`, then the first letter is added twice in the `hits` array. Here's the output in this case: `["M", "M", "a", "n", "i", "s", "h", "M", "a", "n", "i", "s", "h"]`

Comment: That's because your code is "inaccurate". That M comes from "My", not from "Manish". My answer didn't fix all your logical problems (which unfortunately are a plenty), just the last letter you asked about. One step at a time :-) (you should learn to work with a debugger by the way)

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier with [**`indexOf();`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```js
var name = 'Manish';
var str = 'Hey, how are you \\ndoing? My name is Manish. It\'s a really hot day in here. Nice to meet you \\nManish. Bye';
if (str.indexOf(name)>-1) {
 alert('Name was found');
} else {
 alert('Your name wasn\'t found');
}
```

Comment: Regex seems to be the wrong tool here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: You are absolutely right, I didn't think about that. Thank you, I'll edit. @Bergi

Answer (score 0):

You are adding 1 to your counter variables when you make the comparison:

```
if(!(text[j+1] === myName[k+1]))
```

but then you are adding the character without adding 1 to the counter variables:

```
hits.push(text[j]);
```

Just don't add 1 to your counter variables:

```
if(!(text[j] === myName[k]))
```

There are other comments I could make about your code, but since you are learning, I hesitate to say too much.  I should say this, at least:  Look what happens to your output, when you change `text` to this:

```
var text = "Hey, how are you doing? My name is Manish. My, it's a really hot day in here. \
Maybe I'll go outside. Nice to meet you Manish. Bye";
```

Comment: I modified the inner counter variables as you said, but then the first letter of the name seems to appear twice at the start of the `hits` array. Here's the output: `["M", "M", "a", "n", "i", "s", "h", "M", "a", "n", "i", "s", "h"]` when I use `if(!(text[j] === myName[k]))`. Also, please briefly mention about the comments you had in mind. I might not be able to get all of them now, but it would certainly help me down the line.

Comment: Start with the one comment I gave you.  If you change `text` to be the value in my last comment, look at the output.  You get `["M", "M", "a", "n", "i", "s", "h", "M", "M", "a", "M", "a", "n", "i", "s", "h"]`.  Besides the extra `"M"` at the start, you now also have a `"M", "M", "a"` in the middle.  Why do those show up?  Can you figure it out, or do you want me to just tell you?